# How did Jacobs know who Caesar was?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2011, rise-of-the-planet-of-the-apes

In *Rise of the Planet of the Apes*, Jacobs (the executive from Gensys) says that the leader of the apes

> must be killed, and points him out to the sniper when flying around the San Francisco bridge. Ignoring the fact that killing Caesar would likely have done nothing,

how did Jacobs know who Caesar was and what he looked like?  The movie makes it blatantly obvious that Caesar was kept secret from Jacobs.

Answer (score 5):

Jacobs did not know who Caesar was. He observed the apes from

> the helicopter and noticed the lead ape. On the bridge, for example, Caesar is in the lead and raises his hand and cries "Wait!" to halt the advance.

Caesar is also easy to identify:

> he has a prominent birth mark on his chest, and at the time, he was the only ape walking with a straightened spine.

If Caesar had been

> killed at that point, the the apes would have charged the armed police units and gotten decimated.

That would have probably ended the rebellion.

Comment: When Caesar yelled, there was a heavy fog bank in place.  The birthmark doesn't mean much, but the straightened spine might.  Still not sure how Caesar getting killed by the sniper would have made a difference - IIRC the only opportunity came after the attack from above and below (when the majority of the police force was already dealt with).

Comment: I disagree that the birthmark is important, Jacobs has never seen Caesar - he was removed from Gensys as a newborn in secret, and I don't recall it being revealed to Gensys that an ape from the initial trials was kept.  When Will reveals that he's been using AZ112 on his father, he never mentions Caesar.